# Match discrete categorical data between two tables (R)

Tags: r, dataframe, columnsorting

I'm having an issue connecting two ID's and there corresponding categorical values for two different tables.

I have 2 example tables defined as,

**table1**

| ID |
| --- |
| 123 |
| 222 |
| 451 |
| 314 |
| 951 |

**table2**

| ID | Category ID |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 |
| 123 | 1 |
| 451 | 2 |
| 451 | 2 |
| 101 | 3 |

What I want to do is align the Category ID in **table2** so that it correctly corresponds with the ID in **table1** and also, if an id in **table1** appears that is not in **table2**, the category ID should take the value -1. Here is what I want **table1** to look like:

| ID | Category ID |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 |
| 222 | -1 |
| 451 | 2 |
| 314 | -1 |
| 951 | -1 |

I have a solution that (I think) works, code below, but it is computationally very long as I have over 500,000 data points in each table, so I would much prefer a simpler solution, which I'm sure exists, but I cannot come up with. Any help would be great, thanks.

```
new_category_id = numeric()
for (i in 1:nrow(table1)){
  for (j in 1:nrow(table2)){
    
    if (table1$ID[i] == table2$ID[j]){
      new_category_id = append(new_category_id, table2$"Category ID"[j])
      break
      
    }}

  if (!(table1$ID[i] %in% table2$ID)){
    new_category_id = append(new_category_id, -1)
  }
}

table1["Category ID"] = new_category_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `left_join` the two, and replace `NA` using `replace_na()` in `mutate()`.

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(table1, 
          distinct(table2),
          by  = "ID") %>% 
  mutate(CategoryID = replace_na(CategoryID, -1))

   ID CategoryID
1 123          1
2 222         -1
3 451          2
4 314         -1
5 951         -1
```

Comment: I knew there must be an easier solution, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `data.table` alternative. You can join the tables together by `Category ID` and replace `NA` where there is no match with -1. It is not clear if `Category_ID` is always the same for the same `ID`; in this case, just keeping the first match in the second data.table.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(dt1)
setDT(dt2)

dt3 <- dt2[dt1, on = .(ID), mult = "first", nomatch = NA]
setnafill(dt3, cols = "Category_ID", fill = -1)
```

**Output**

```
    ID Category_ID
1: 123           1
2: 222          -1
3: 451           2
4: 314          -1
5: 951          -1
```